# Android - TalkBack accessibility focus on back button

Tags: android, android-xml, speech-to-text, talkback, accessibility

My understanding of talkback is that after back navigation, the focus should be restored on the element triggering the view change. I have some constraint layouts that act as buttons, however, when I navigate back the focus does not restore on the constraint layout that triggered the navigation but instead the overall root view.

I can see the expected behaviour when using standard buttons for navigation.

Is this normal behaviour? Is it possible to achieve this with constraint layouts that act as buttons?

Answer (score -1):

The way that sequential navigation order is determined in Web content is defined by the technology of the content.For example simple HTML defines sequential navigation via the notion of tabbing order. If no scripting or tabindex attributes are used, the navigation order is the order that components appear in the content stream. The navigation focus order can be modified programmatically. It is generally seen that the focus moves from left to right , top to bottom. Acc. to WCAG guidelines, it suggests that the focus order may not be identical to the programmatically determined reading order (see Success Criterion 1.3.2) as long as the user can still understand and operate the Web page.
Reference: [Refer here for more details](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-focus-order.html)

Cheers!
Mohita